# I am not getting the value from database

Tags: php, mysqli, distinct

In my code I am unable to get the value from database. In my database there is a value **general knowledge**. But I am getting the value **genereal** instead of **general knowledge**.

```
$r_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category_id FROM questions";

$r_query = mysqli_query($con, $r_sql);
if (!$r_query) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
while($r_row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)){
    echo "<option value = ".$r_row['category_id'].">" .$r_row['category_id']."</option>";
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your post that would cause the issue you describe, and your SELECT does not contain a WHERE condition that would cause this issue either. There is insufficient information in your post to use to answer this question. Based on what you've provided here, it is not possible that you're getting the results you claim you are.

Comment: Your problem is likely in the INSERT, not the SELECT.

Comment: Please provide the database table information relevant to the question.

Comment: echo "<option value = ".$r_row['category_id'].">" .$r_row['category_id']."</option>"; As I know problem is in this line. I want to get <option value = "general knowledge">general knowledge</option> but i am getting <option value = general>general knowledge</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a space in the value, but you don't put quote marks around the value of the HTML attribute.  You're probably diagnosing this problem inside your browser and it's hiding the real echo'd output to try and make sense of the broken code.

```
echo '<option value="' . $r_row['category_id'] . '">' . $r_row['category_id'] . '</option>';
```

Your original output was

```
<option value = general knowledge>general knowledge</option>
```

whereas it should be

```
<option value="general knowledge">general knowledge</option>
```

which the above PHP should generate.

The browser interpreted it as `<option value="general">` and discarded the 'knowledge' part because that's not a valid attribute name, and it wasn't clear that it "goes with" the 'value'.

Notice even the syntax highligher on this website puts 'knowledge' in red, just like 'value' because it thinks it's a new attribute.

I don't know what browser you have, but in Chrome if I just go to 'view source' rather than using the developer tools, I can see the REAL output.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the SQL error would come from any code we've discussed in this question.  Might want to consider any other SQL queries you've made.